# How to change the default text in Search Bar in IOS?

Tags: ios, text, uisearchbar

HI I develop an application in IOS and I meet a problem that I want to change the default text which is "search" in search bar to "Key in video title to search". How to do it ? Please help me Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Before asking such questions, please take a minute to scan the documentation. In 30 seconds you have found the proper `UISearchBar` property.

Comment: sorry becuase i'm newbie, next time i will scan doc first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `UISearchBar` and the `UITextField` have this property of a `placeholder` which is the default text in the fields.

1.Change it from the Interface Builder.
[image: Interface Builder]

2.Change it through code

```
self.searchBarObject.placeholder = @"Key In Video Title To Search";
```

Read [what Apple has written](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html) about the `UISearchField`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the plain old `placeholder` property:

```
mySearchBar.placeholder = @"Foo!";
```

[Relevant documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/placeholder).

It can also be changed within Interface Builder:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the placeholder property

```
sBar.placeholder = @"Key in video title to search";
```